# Async Calls in Typescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, typescript

I am messing around with asynchronous calls. I want to generate a dashboard and initialise it with the id "1". It generates elements, which I can click on and generates another dashboard with elements. It is like a tree.

So I can generate the dashboard with id 1 but I can't click on it. I know, that it is because of the async call in my code but I have no idea actually how to fix it. I was messing around with Deferred Objects but it didn't helped me. So this is the basis:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="scripts/Dashboard.ts" />


$(document).ready(function ()
{
    init();
    jQuery('.Reference').click(function()
    {
        var classId = jQuery(this).attr('class');
        jQuery('#content').remove();
        generateDashboard(parseInt(classId), (d: Dashboard): void =>
        {
            d.printDashboard();
        });

    });
});

function generateDashboard(param: number, callback: (d: Dashboard) => void): void
{
    new Dashboard(param, callback);
}


function init()
{
    generateDashboard(1, (d: Dashboard): void =>
    {
        d.printDashboard();
    });

}
```

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: Here the generated HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dashboard</title>
<link type="text/css" href="app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="jquery.js">
<script src="app.js">
<script src="scripts/Helper.js">
<script src="scripts/Dashboard.js">
<script src="scripts/Elements.js">
<script src="scripts/Leaf.js">
<script src="scripts/Status.js">
<script src="scripts/Threshold.js">
<script src="scripts/Item.js">
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="dashboard"></h1>
<div id="content">
<div class="1">Element-1</div>
<div class="31">Element-4</div>
<div id="31" class="Reference">Element-2</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you're experiencing?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but you probably want to keep the references to the `Dashboard`s your create, otherwise they can be garbage collected and their code never run (ie. the callback never called).

Comment: jQuery('.Reference').click(function() doesn't react, or: I can't click on smthg

Comment: Are you sure you've got the class name correctly specified? It's case sensitive. What does the HTML look like?

Comment: I'll come back to work tomorrow and give you an update then :)